# Problem: Integral and fractions

Tags: integration

Please, help me with this excersice, it is easy, but I am practicing. Dont be rude. thanks

$\int$ ${1\over {\sqrt x}}$ dx

Comment: Would it help you if I told you that it could be re-written as: $\int x^{-\frac{1}{2}}dx$

Comment: You must show what you tried . In that way, MSE-people will  probably post an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\frac1{\sqrt x}=\frac1{x^{1/2}}=x^{-1/2}$$

Then, by using integral power rules (add 1 to exponent & divide down in front) you should get the answer:

$2 x^{1/2}$ + C

Which can also be re-written as: $2\sqrt{x}$ = C

Either is accepted.

Comment: Don't forget your $+C$ at the end if it's an indefinite integral.

Answer (score 0):

Hints:

(1) For **any**

$$\;-1\neq m\in\Bbb R\;,\;\;\int x^mdx=\frac{x^{m+1}}{m+1}+C\;$$

(2) We have that

$$\frac1{\sqrt x}=\frac1{x^{1/2}}=x^{-1/2}$$

Answer (score 0):

Remember that primitive (antiderivative) of $x^\alpha$ is ${x^{\alpha+1}\over \alpha+1}$. Now write $1/\sqrt{x}=x^{-1/2}$ and you get

$$\int{dx\over\sqrt{x}}=\int x^{-1\over 2}dx={x^{1\over 2}\over {1\over 2}}=2\sqrt{x}$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\int\frac{dx}{\sqrt x}=|\sqrt x=t\Rightarrow x=t^2 \Rightarrow dx=2tdt|=$$
$$\int\frac{2tdt}{t}=2\int\frac{tdt}{t}=2\sqrt x+C$$